# How to get line of hex codes (\x) to hex address (0x) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, hex

How do I get bytes this line of hex ASCII to a hex address as shown below?

I've managed to separate them to each line, but am having issues with the python 3 hex() as it throws errors such as str type when I try to do something like say line.hex().

**Input**
`\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\x00`

**Output**

```
0xDDCCBBAA
0x2211FFEE
0x66554433
0x00998877
```

**My Code**

```
import re

a=r"\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\x00"

r = '\n'.join(re.findall('................|.$', a))

for line in r.splitlines(): 
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\x00"
print("\n".join([hex(ord(c)) for c in s]))
```

Will output:

```
0xaa
0xbb
0xcc
0xdd
0xee
0xff
0x11
0x22
0x33
0x44
0x55
0x66
0x77
0x88
0x99
0x0
```

Is this what you needed? This assumes the input string `s` is a string consisting of Unicode characters. It would be quite helpful to know what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I read the question to require statically sized hex encoding of 32 bit words (according to the output). Of course, some feedback of the author would be required to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I always verify that my input is correct before I start doing anything. So using regexp, I came up with the following:

```
import re

a=r"\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\x00"

# matches a word consisting of 4 bytes encoded as \xHH where H is any hex character
listOfFourHexBytes = re.findall(r'(?:\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){4}', a)
if (len(a) != 4 * 16 or len(listOfFourHexBytes) != 4):
    raise Exception("Input does not consist of 16 hexadecimal bytes")
for fourHexbytes in listOfFourHexBytes:
    justFourHexBytes = re.sub(r'\\x', '', fourHexbytes)
    print("0x" + justFourHexBytes)

    # not asked for, but generate number from hex value first
    n = int(justFourHexBytes, 16)
    print("0x%08X" % n)
```

It first looks for actual hex bytes in the format you asked for, in groups of 4 hex encoded bytes. Then it checks if there are indeed 4 of those, making sure that the input string is of the correct size (no spurious skipped characters). Then it iterates over those, removing the `\x` from the strings. The next step is of course easy as pie, just add `0x` to the result and print it out.

Usually you need to do something with the values, so I added the `int` conversion for free.

Comment: Any comment or edit on the python code is appreciated, Python is not my first language.